# If one method handles many events, is there a way for the handler to tell what event it's responding to?

Tags: c#, debugging, events, delegates, event-handling

This is for debugging purposes. And I can't use Visual Studio for debugging because I'm testing on a different device.

Right now, the best I can do is see what specific `EventArgs` derived class is being passed to the handler. Is there a way to get more specific that that and see what exact event is being invoked in the method that's handling it?

```
ContentControl cc = my_button;
cc.DragEnter += LogEvent;
cc.DragLeave += LogEvent;
cc.GotFocus += LogEvent;
cc.GotMouseCapture += LogEvent;
cc.GotStylusCapture += LogEvent;

...

private void LogEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ContentControl cc = (ContentControl)sender;
    my_textBlock.Inlines.Add(cc.Name + " " + e.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

I suppose I could put this question in more general terms and ask: can a method tell what delegate is invoking it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to pull it out of the call stack.  Take a look at `Enviroment.StackTrace` or `System.Diagnostics.StackTrace`

Comment: Dealing with stack trace is very risky. Debug and release stack trace may be different due to compiler optimizations. Code may be obfuscated in future, so the solution will stop working

Comment: Thanks, oldovets. I think it would be okay if the code is just for debugging purposes, right?

Comment: Okay, Enviroment.StackTrace is a long string and it's hard to extract just the right piece of it. But after some experimentation, new `System.Diagnostics.StackTrace().GetFrame(4).GetMethod().Name` seems to work pretty well.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
cc.DragEnter += (sender,e) => LogEvent("DragEnter",sender);
cc.DragLeave += (sender,e) => LogEvent("DragLeave",sender);
cc.GotFocus += (sender,e) => LogEvent("GotFocus",sender);
cc.GotMouseCapture += (sender,e) => LogEvent("GotMouseCapture",sender);
cc.GotStylusCapture += (sender,e) => LogEvent("GotStylusCapture",sender);

private void LogEvent(string eventName,object sender) {
    ContentControl cc = (ContentControl)sender;
    my_textBlock.Inlines.Add(cc.Name + " " + eventName);
}
```

Comment: It's clever, but it definitely slows down the process of typing 30 or 40 event listeners.